# Laravel http API display in JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, collections

I got a task and I need your help. Firstly I would like to show you my `App\Repositories\xyz.php`:

```php
public function getcars(): Collection
{
    return collect([new Car(...))];
}
```

There is a lot of data in it. And my task is that I have to use a Http Get Api endpoint to show ONE random `Car` from these in JSON format. I made a new controller file for this and the route for it but I don't know how can I continue it.

Thank you for your Reply!

Answer (score 0):

if Car is a model use :

```
App\Models\User::inRandomOrder()->first();
```